# Multiple change events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `<select>` menus, each with change events working on them. Break down of the code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // some code

    $("#selectOne").change(function() {
        // some code inc ajax request

        $("#selectTwo").change(function() {
            // some code inc a different ajax request
        });

        $("#selectThree").change(function() {
            // some code inc a yet another ajax request

        });
    });
});
```

The problem with the above is that, while selectOne works fine, and selectTwo seems to work fine also, if I change selectThree, the code for both selectTwo AND selectThree fires at the same time. Depending on the sequence of selection of any of the 3 selects, the response of selectThree.change can be to display and hide each of the previous responses, before settling on displaying an incorrect response.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // some code

    $("#selectOne").change(function() {
        // some code inc ajax request
    });

    $("#selectTwo").change(function() {
        // some code inc a different ajax request
    });

    $("#selectThree").change(function() {
        // some code inc a yet another ajax request

    });
});
```

In this scenario, selectOne works fine, but selectTwo and selectThree don't respond to change.

Is there a way of correcting any of this, so that as each element is changed, only the correct change event is fired?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Comment: Your second block of code should work just find. The bug has to be in the code displaying and hiding previous selects.

Comment: Is rather long - [try here](http://www.insightdesign.com.au/test.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when your document is loaded there is no select elements with id "selectTwo" or "selectThree". Similarly in the first case, there is no "selectThree" when the eventhandler of "selectOne" executes. That's why the corresponding event handlers does not execute. There is two way you can handle this proplem.

**1 -** Assing handlers when the elements are created.

**2 -** Use `.on()` instead of `.change()`:

```
$('body').on("change", "#selectOne", function () {});

$('body').on("change", "#selectTwo", function () {});

$('body').on("change", "#selectThree", function () {});
```

Comment: jQuery 1.7 deprecated live, we use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event handlers now. Which is invoked as `$('element').on('event, '#bindedElement', function(){})`;

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks. Edited as suggested.

Comment: I tried the 2nd option above with no luck, change on selectTwo doesn't fire anything. I'm not sure how to use the 'bindedElement' as @Ohgodwhy recommended - can you give me an example using my breakdown please?

Comment: The whole point of using on is to not use the $('element') on an element that does not yet exist. So your lines of code should be something like `$('body').on("change", '#selectOne', function () {alert(1);});`

Comment: @SimonMunyard Try to alert $("selectX").length before assigning change handler. You will see it will evaluate zero.

Comment: Success!! Here's what worked:
    $('body').on('change', "#selectOne", function(){) );
    $('body').on('change', "#selectTwo", function(){) );
    $('body').on('change', "#selectThree", function(){) );
Thanks all.